# integrate google oauth for gmail login/ signup system

Tags: python, django

I am designing an application to be accessible on both app and web. I want my customers to login/ signup via gmail as well. for this I need to integrate google auth system for social logins.
My end goal is to establish a connection with google and extract user data such as name, profile_pic, dob, sub from that.

I followed the below approach for my app and it worked.

```
from google.oauth2 import id_token
from google.auth.transport import requests
id_info = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(token, requests.Request(), google_client_id)
print(id_info['sub'], id_info['email'])
```

this works fine for app and gives me all user data.

Now, when i try to do this for web, from all the ways i could find, I tried with google API calls as below

in web, we get code in callback API request from google as a request param. We have to fetch an auth token from google in exchange of this code and then use that token to fetch user data. (That's how it works, as per my understanding)

```
 data = {
            'code': code,
            'client_id': my_client_id,
            'client_secret': my_client_secret_key,
            'redirect_uri': redirect_uri,
            'grant_type': 'authorization_code'
        }
    response = requests.post('https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token', data=data)
    if not response.ok:
        logger.info('Could not get access token from Google.')
        return

    access_token = response.json()['access_token']
    response2 = requests.get(
                'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo',
                params={'access_token': access_token}
            )
    return response2.json()
```

now in this chunk, i am able to fetch user_data if i give any access_token. But the problem is while fetching access_token from code using this code.
I get response as

> {'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'Bad Request'}

or

> {'error': 'unauthorized_client', 'error_description': 'Unauthorized'}

Where am I doing the mistake. P.S. my credentials are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You should use built-in Django apps for social auth integration. Much easier for implementing all third-parties simultaneously.

```
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
```

Comment: i tried with 'allauth.socialaccount' but it does not let me use the "code" to fetch access token, the code is my request param and hence shouldn't my further logic be based on that?